# canvas почему изображение стирается а не поворачивается?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

нужно по кнопке поворачивать изображение, я вроде всё правильно написал, а оно стирается почему то

```js
var img;
var tttAlt = 0;
var tttLong = 0;
var tttScale = 0;

function draw() { //upload
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, (img.height * canvas.width) / img.width); //вписывание в ширину
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function turn() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
  var rectX = canvas.width / 2,
    rectY = canvas.height / 2;

  ctx.translate(-0, -500);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, (img.height * canvas.width) / img.width); //вписывание в ширину
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turn()">turn</button>


<input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage" size="1" class="input_input_style">

<body style="background-color:3F6E6F;">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

  <script src="config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Может, я что-то не знаю про canvas, но не понимаю, что у вас должно быть в ф-ии draw в анонимной ф-ии на img.onload в переменной canvas? Не вижу, чтобы эта переменная определялась.

Comment: как что?) туда с компьютера загружается картинка,  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage"

Comment: Где у вас в js определяется переменная `canvas`? Вставьте в img.onload код `console.log(canvas);`, что в консоль выведет?

Comment: спасибо за помощь, я всё исправил. осталась одна проблема - как мне высчитать точку вокруг которой поворачивать - ctx.translate(-0,-500); это не половина ширины и половина высоты, а что то странное